# Datatable behaviour when using filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

The way datatables is handling selections is giving my a bit of a headache.

I have a 4-step wizard. In step 2 of the wizard some items can be selected using a multiselect.

Step 3 offers an option selection for the in step 2 selected items where 1 option per item can be selected using a checkbox. This step also contains a 'Select all' checkbox that can be used to select the option for all items shown in the datatable. This is not a datatables, but a simple button outside of the datatable that uses jQuery to set all the editable checkboxes.

Step 4 offers an overview of the selected items with their options.

Using this wizard in the following scenario and outcomes:

- Select a couple of items in step 3 (for this example, use 3 selected items)
- Use the 'Select all' button to select the option for each of the 3 items
- See the confirmation in step 4 that the option is selected for each item
- Go back to step 3 and use the 'Select all' button to deselect the option for each item
- Now using the datatable filtering to only show item 2 in the datatable and select the option for this item
- Go to step 4 and see that the option is selected for each of the 3 items (**<- Unexpected behaviour**)
- Go back to step 3 and remove the filtering on the database (change nothing else)
- Go to step 4 and see that only item 2 has the option selected.

It looks like the 'hidden' items in the datatable only get updated when visible to the user. This seems like odd behaviour to me. Is there a way to avoid or work around this type of behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? You can create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).

Comment: @andrewJames I wish I could, but I'm using a (bought) template that I can't just include in an example or reduce to the code needed to provide a minimal reproducible example. Because I'm pretty sure the 'problem' lies within datatables and/or jQuery reading from datatables. Therefore I'm hoping that using the, admittedly sub-ideal, approach of textual explenation could be enough for someone to recognize this problem if he/she as came across this before.

Comment: You should ask whoever sold you the template for help, in that case. (Maybe you already have.) It is unlikely that the community here will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I didn't find the cause of this problem, but I know a working work-around. Maybe it's usefull for someone in the future:

Because the problem seems to exists in the visibility of the items when a filter is used in the datatable, I've tried to clear this filter and redraw the table before proceeding to the next step.

```
table.DataTable().search('').draw();
```

Doing this ensures all items are visible before they are being read from the datatable. This works as a work-around for this datatable problem.